# What is diffrence between actor, actor instance and actorref

Tags: akka

What is actually an Actor in context of code. Is it the java class which extends UnTypedActor ? i.e. 1 Actor=1 Class. 
If yes, do we have multiple instance of it, simple referred using actorref. How does multiple instance of actorref for same actor differs from each other ?

What do we mean by actor failing or restart of an actor ? Do we just reload the class with last persisted data variables ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actor's behavior is represented by its class in code.

- in runtime one logical actor has one (but not always same) instance in the system (there might be more in memory before GC).
- One class may correspond to several logical actors - each has different address.
- Actor instance is an instance of `UntypedActor` (or just `Actor` in scala) adressed in Actors system.
- [ActorRef](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html) is reference to the one (local or remote), but not always same instance (it's changing when actor is restarting), e.g. to the one logical Actor with its own address.

Failing is, simply saying, throwing an exception from `onReceive` (`receive` in Scala) method. When actor fails it sends `Terminated` message to its [supervisor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html) and (depending on SupervisorStrategy) may restart or stop. Restarting means:

- calling `preRestart` method of actor's instance
- creating new instance (which will be referenced from the same ActorRef after re-creation)
- calling postRestart method of newely created instance. Actor's state is becoming lost after `preRestart`.

Comment: If I am correct, mailbox is tied to ActorRef, not Actor, hence if we have multiple ActorRef for same Actor, won't that defeat the purpose of synchronization among messages with different ActorRef.
What would be a practical use case where you would like to have multiple ActorRef ?

Comment: if you mean multiple ActorRef to the one logical instance. They're immutable (ActorRef's), so no much reason - you can send the same ActorRef to everyone. But remote actor may have different `ActorRef`s in different JVMs

Comment: You're not correct, mailbox is tied to the actor's instance (optionally). It depends on dispatcher, which decides to which instance to send a message for processing. It might use ActorRef to to lookup the Actor's instance. "synchronization among messages with different ActorRef" even if they was different - they are pointing to the same instance, when you do `tell` the mesasge+actorRef goes to the **dispatcher** not inside ActorRef

Comment: What do you mean by "One class may correspond to several logical actors - each has different address"

Comment: I mean you can create several actors for one class. Don't know how you do it in Java, in Scala it's ActorSystem.actorOf(Props[ActorClass], "name"), so you can create several logical actor's of ActorClass with different names. Each will have different address (ending with name). Each will have different ActoRef. Btw, even if you obtain several actorRefs in one JVM to one logical actor somehow (you need some special ActorRefFactory for that) - they will be equal in terms of `equals` method.

Comment: By the way you may read all about this at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html

Comment: I understand how to do that, but what is the practical use case where we would like to have several logical actors with different names for one class ?

Comment: worker is a practical case. you may want to distribute many messages (with same type) through several (or many) actors. Usualy it's done in combination with routers - http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/routing.html.